# Final Cut: how to playback sequence while capturing video?

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro

When you open "log and capture" window, you can't use other FCP windows anymore. How can I listen to already captured video?

I want to record my solo on top of rhythm which was captured before. I don't want to synchronize videos.  If I just could listen to the first video then everything would be fine.

I would like to do the same thing as in Logic studio, listen to 3 tracks playing and record a 4th one in real time.

How can I achieve this in final cut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I recall, you can't.  I would tape your solo on your camera while playing your time line and then importing that video back into FCP once it's done.

Comment: i don't want to sync audio =( logic studio for video would be great.. =/

Comment: Gotcha.  There's still no way to play the timeline while you're also in log-and-capture mode.  Basically, you have to use your camera, or an audio recorder, or something to capture your solo while you play your timeline for your rhythm background track.  Alternatively, you could export that, play it in Quicktime, while importing your live track with Log and Capture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of accessing the rest of the FCP program while capturing, because your computer is allocating all of the 2.5GB of Ram to capturing to prevent a smooth capture and no dropped frames, since FCP is software based and not hardware based this is not possible.

Comment: what about having 16gb of ram... and use each cpu core for one capturing.. what's the problem to capture god damned webcam which uses not more like 20mb ram =/ what's wrong with this world